# inequality proof of $x^{y-1} \ge xy$

Tags: number-theory, inequality

How to prove $x^{y-1}\geq xy$ with
$x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ with $x,y\geq 3$ . Do I need induction? Or is there an elegant way?

Comment: Number theory? ${}{}$

Comment: I get this problem in an number theory course

Comment: Induction works for natural numbers, which in this particular inequality is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^{y-2} \geq 3^{y-2} \geq  y,\ \forall x,y \geq 3$$
where the last inequality can be proven by induction in a very simple way for $y \geq 3$ integer.

For $y \geq 3$ you can use the function $f(y)=3^{y-2}-y$ and show that is increasing on $[3,\infty)$.

Comment: I can't see a "very simple way" for doing induction over $\mathbb{R}$. Maybe the question was over $\mathbb{N}$, or you need to show that $f(y)=3^{y-2}-y$ is increasing for $y\geq3$ (that is true, and can be done with derivative).

Comment: Sorry. I forgot that $y \geq 3$ was real.

Comment: I have to proof: $x^{y-1}\geq xy$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x,y\ge 3$

Comment: @evenpoly: Ok, but can't you see the connection?

Comment: Ok I see it. The derivative of ${3}^{y-2}-y$ is $\frac{d}{dy}3^{y-1}-y={3}^{y-2}\ln  \left( 3 \right) -1$. And this is greater than 0 for y>2. 
So we have $3^{y-1}-y > 0$ for $y>3$ and the function $3^{y-1}-y$ is  monotonically nondecreasing for y>3. So the inequality holds. Is that ok?

Comment: @evenpoly: Yes, that's ok.

Comment: Great. Thank you all for your help. My idea of induction was really worse since the situations takes place in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I can see a relation with "number theory"... anyone know a simple approach that don't require derivative?